# Comparing AIC, BIC and HQC for selection of nested model?

Tags: regression, aic, splines, bic, nested-models

I am working with spline regression and in this step what I want to do is to somehow reduce the number of knots by applying backward selection.
Technically what I am doing is to delete sequentially one knot (the one leading the the smallest RSS). At the end I am left with a series of nested models and I have to choose one to be my definitive model.

Some authors propose to use BIC in order to select the model, but after some test I've realised that using AIC or HQC lead to very different results.
Even though I am aware that it is due to the different penalisation in each criteria I would like to knot if there's some consensus about the decision rule in a case like this one.
Should I pick the IC according to some thumb rule ?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips, a perfectly fine request, but doesn't it suggest the answer is going to be data specific and so only one user (the one working with this particular data set) would benefit from it? As an alternative, it could be helpful to lay out your reasoning in a principled way such that the ideas could be applied more broadly.

Comment: As you state, the request is perfectly fine.

Comment: I agree with @RichardHardy I would prefer you to explain me what are the factors to consider and why you are interested in the data, what would you look for?

Comment: Having not seen the data, I cannot answer the question - for example, I suspect that there are more than two data points yet cannot confirm whether this is true.